# What's the difference between a cursor and a trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb, cursors

I'm triying to understand why use a Cursosr or really how they work (I'm a newbie).

I don't really find a clear purpose for using it.

How does it compare to a trigger?

Comment: cursor and triggers are very different concepts, can you elaborate on how you plan to use a cursor instead of a trigger? If not, perhaps you can add some details on what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: If you want an example, check out my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, a cursor is used to iterate through a result set that was returned by a `SELECT` statement.

Cursors can be used in stored procedures, stored functions, and *triggers*.

A trigger is a stored program executed automatically to respond to a specific event like an insert, update, or delete.

As you can see, these are very different concepts and have very different purposes.

I suggest you review these links for the basics on both of these concepts: 
[Triggers](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx/), [Cursors](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/)

Answer (score 2):

## Overview

- A cursor points to row in a result set (data)
- A trigger (instruction) executes when something is modified (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE).

## Example

If you want a real world example. You're going to the store to pick up groceries. You've got six dollars. Each item cost two dollars. You need to get three items. The list works out. If all things go as planned these items should be in your cart, and you should have 0 dollars at the end.

1. Oranges
2. Beer
3. Bananas

You just arrived at the grocery store, you look at your list

1. Oranges  **<- Cursor pointing here.**
2. Beer
3. Bananas

You just got the Oranges, processing that item on the list.

1. Orange
2. Beer  **<- Cursor pointing here.**
3. Bananas

You get the next item from the list and you head off to the Beer aisle; but, the wife called up and she needs prunes. You need to

1. Check your funds.
2. Check your list.
3. Compute if you have enough, then either

   - Assert *"No can do"*
   - Add it to your list, effectively a *"Got ya covered."*

That's an instruction. It *triggered* when your wife tried to get you to pick up prunes. In order to keep your list sound, and because you value data integrity you tell your wife *"No can do"* resisting her commit. You hope your wife can handle the assertion without blowing up. You continue to seek out Beer.

In the real world, you would have continued to the Beer anyway because databases also don't like to be nagged nor interrupt their workers when they're doing their job.

## See also

Regardless of database, you should always head over to the PostgreSQL docs for general ideas about how something works as they're far more verbose,

- [*Cursors* in plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) (procedural)
- [`DECLARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) [`FETCH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html) PostgreSQL's interactive triggers. An API you don't always get because it's not in the spec

  > The SQL standard defines FETCH for use in embedded SQL only.
- [*Triggers*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html)

An important note is that these mention syntax, but they're not strictly syntax. For triggers the more strictly syntax doc is [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)